# str::contains fails with "expected an Fn<(char,)> closure, found Cow<'_, str>"

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to check if `name` contains `file_name` or if `file_name` contains `name` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd5a777fa77d80d7b5d3a7ab3d8ce9fb)):

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let slashes = Regex::new(r"[\\\/]").unwrap();
    let name = String::from("firstname");
    let file_name = String::from("secondst/ring");
    let replaced_name = slashes.replace_all(&file_name, "_");
    if name.contains(&replaced_name) || replaced_name.contains(&name) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `Fn<(char,)>` closure, found `Cow<'_, str>`
   --> src/main.rs:8:22
    |
8   |     if name.contains(&replaced_name) || replaced_name.contains(&name) {
    |             -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(char,)>` closure, found `Cow<'_, str>`
    |             |
    |             required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Fn<(char,)>` is not implemented for `Cow<'_, str>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FnOnce<(char,)>` for `&Cow<'_, str>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Pattern<'_>` for `&Cow<'_, str>`
note: required by a bound in `core::str::<impl str>::contains`
```

I tried the following variants with no success:

```rust
if name.contains(file_name) || file_name.contains(name) {
```

```rust
if name.contains(&file_name) || file_name.contains(&name) {
```

```rust
if name.to_string().contains(&file_name) || file_name.to_string().contains(&name) {
```

Comment: Try `contains(&*name)`. This will do `Cow<str>` -> `str` -> `&str`.

Comment: Try: `name.contains(replaced_name.as_ref())`

Comment: @MartinGallagher that doesn't even work on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7fc0a961ba7ca29635c8d31e4b7a199

Comment: @Shepmaster you changed the title of my question, then marked it as duplicate and in the duplicate message is saying: `Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.` well that was the reason why I asked a new question because the previous question doesn't answer and solve the problem!

Comment: *doesn't answer and solve the problem* — sure it does: "This means that you need to pass a `&str` to `contains`". The only tweak is that you have a different path to get from `Cow` to `&str`, which is [what I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397472/strcontains-fails-with-expected-an-fnchar-closure-found-cow-str#comment126198895_71397472) and have now added a second duplicate.